# Arabic text is showing Ø¨Ù†Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù in PDF from itext

Tags: java, rest, pdf, itext, restful-architecture

I am creating PDF using itext in java.I have problem with arabic text .
Arabic text 'بناية المهى ط اﻻ رضي-الفنار 
 ' it is showing Ø¨Ù†Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù.
I have a rest webservice that is returning 'Ø¨Ù†Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù' for above arabic data.
This is the code for **RestService**.

```
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
public Response getdata(DataRequest request) throws Exception {
    DataResponse output = facade.getSummary(request);
    return Response.ok(output).build();

}
```

below is **Restclient** code that is accesing above service code to fetch data

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8").post(ClientResponse.class,
            request);

    if (clientResponse.getStatus() == UIConstants.RESPONSE_SUCCESS) {
        response = (PolicySummaryResponse) RestClient.unMarshalJson(
                PolicySummaryResponse.class,
                clientResponse.getEntityInputStream());}
```

when i am showing this response in JSP it is showing arabic data.
But when i am creating pdf it is showing 'Ø¨Ù†Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù' 
This is the code for pdf

```
PdfPTable ownerTable = new PdfPTable(4);ownerTable.addCell(owneraddress);
```

I tried this also but no luck

```
Font arabicfont = FontFactory.getFont("/com/ARIALN.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        PdfPCell addrCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(policy.getPayor().getAddress1().trim(), arabicfont));
        addrCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
        ownerTable.addCell(addrCell);
```

this is showing all blank only a **-** there.
Please help

Comment: You have an encoding problem for your input text

Comment: @blagae can you please elaborate. this same response is showing correctly in webpage(jsp)

Answer (score 2):

You have an encoding problem, as evidenced by the fact that your output doesn't look anything like your input. I'll show you how to diagnose this issue with https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ for the first two characters. Your first two characters بن are encoded in the standard Java encoding notation as follows:

```
\u0628 \u0646
```

This is UTF-16, which is somewhat human-readable. If you encode it in UTF-8, however, you get this completely different byte array:

```
D8 A8 D9 86
```

The fun part is when we start mixing encodings, e.g. using the UTF-8 as input for a UTF-16 String:

```
\u00D8 \u00A8 \u00D9 \u0086
```

This outputs the following three visible characters in the aforementioned website - the same as the start of the String you reported, and also an invisible one (the control character SSA on location 0x86 in Unicode):

```
Ø ¨ Ù
```

I assume that you can't change the way your initial `String` is created, so we'll have to enforce the encoding by using its text in a copy constructor. The easiest way I know to solve this in Java is the following:

```
String line = // your input
line = new String(line.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: what should be my input in the suggested code line =Ø¨Ù†Ø§ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ù?

Comment: It should be the policy.getPayor().getAddress1()

Comment: i tried this String line = policy.getPayor().getAddress1().trim();
   line = new String(line.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   ownerTable.addCell(line); it is showing only a - there

Comment: if required i can change the initial way of creating the string ,i mean service code from where arabic is getting returned in UTF-8 as response

Comment: Then you should use a different font

Comment: please suggest which font to use

Comment: seriously ? you should know best which fonts are on your system, and which ones support Arabic

Comment: I am sry if u get me wrong .I already  tried this font ARIALN.ttf with BaseFont.IDENTITY_H ,i have mentioned in the question. but problem not solved

Comment: Arial narrow doesn't contain characters for Arabic. There is no problem with your iText code, but with your font file.

Comment: Thnks a lot. this solved one problem when address is in arabic it is working fine but when it is in english it is not showing the content.here address could be anything english or arabic

Comment: Beware: `line.getBytes()` uses the underlying platform’s default charset, which is UTF-8 on non-Windows systems, and usually a one-byte charset in Windows (for example, windows-1252 on US versions of Windows).  It’s a good idea to explicitly specify a charset, like `line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`.